Inconsistent posterior from hierarchical survival model
I asked about this question on Stan forum but no one replied so dual posting here. I'd really appreciate some insight, as I'm completely stuck.
I’m trying to do hierarchical survival modeling using the Weibull model. I can fit both the unpooled and hierarchical models fine but I’m baffled by the posterior produced by the latter one.
I’m using the lung data set from the R package survival with age and ph.karno as covariates. In the hierarchical model, I fit separate effects for ph.karno.
The pooled model produces a concentrated (sd = 0.06) posterior for the ph.karno effect, with the 90% CI not containing 0. In the hierarchical model the sex-specific effects have sd > 2 and the population distribution’s sd > 3. Fitting separate models for both sexes produces posteriors similar to the pooled model.
Below is a comparison of the posteriors for the pooled (left) and the hierarchical models (right). To me the hierarchical model’s posterior doesn’t make sense, as I would expect it to be inline with the pooled model. Could you share some insight why this happens?

Here's the code:
library(brms)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)

## Data **************************

my_data <- lung
my_data <- my_data[, c("age", "ph.karno", "status", "time", "sex")]
my_data <- my_data %>% drop_na

# Normalize
my_data[, c("age", "ph.karno")] <- apply(my_data[, c("age", "ph.karno")],
                                          MARGIN = 2,
                                          FUN = function(X) {(X-mean(X))/sd(X)})


## Pooled ************************

# Formula
formula1 <- paste0("time | cens(1-status) ~ age + ph.karno")


# Fit
fit1 <- brm(formula1,
           data = my_data,
           family = weibull(),
           prior = prior(normal(0, 1), class = b), 
           chains = 1)


## Hierarchical ******************

# Formula
formula2 <- paste0("time | cens(1-status) ~ age + ph.karno + (1 + ph.karno || sex)")


# Fit
fit2 <- brm(formula2,
           data = my_data,
           family = weibull(),
           prior = prior(normal(0, 1), class = b), 
           chains = 1, 
           control = list(adapt_delta = 0.99))


## Plot ***********************

p1 <- mcmc_areas(fit1, regex_pars = "b", prob = 0.9)
p2 <- mcmc_areas(fit2, regex_pars = "b_|r_", prob = 0.9)
```


The model results look pretty similar, just with more uncertainty, because you allow for variability between sexes. Looking just at the marginal posteriors may not tell the whole story though, because different model parameters might be correlated a-posteriori. Comparing things like predicted survival curves for different values of the covariates, or across covariate levels plot the 1 year survival  etc. would integrate that out.
